# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create an already created platform view, view id: 0

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**I am trying to build google map from flutter flamework...but this error is really buzzing me off...please help me out...**

2020-02-19 05:16:45.027 24331-24360/com.cookietech.flutter_map E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create an already created platform view, view id: 0
        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:85)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6598)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    , null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
    
    #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
    #3      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:633:54)
    #4      AndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:550:14)
    #5      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:175:29)
    #6      RenderAndroidView.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:156:5)
    #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1746:9)
    #8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #10     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11)
    #11     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:477:7)
    #12     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
    #13     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14)
    #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #18     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1247:11)
    #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:110:13)
    #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
    #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flu
[image]

Comment: Can you show me your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: there u go sir...please take a look..i have pasted pubspec.yaml file on pastebin..
here is the link...
https://pastebin.com/xLx9VsVz

Comment: Could you post your code mate ?

Comment: i can send here my codes...my git link...
but i found the reason may be...
it happens for hot reload or building the app again and again.
i have solved the problem...i am giving my solution as a comment down below...i am sending u my git link here sir. @Ratnadeep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i did to solve the problem was write these commands to terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

then rebuild the app and it works. Also, I noticed a lot of the time that the app behaved unexpectedly. To correct this, I closed the app from the device and rebuilt it again.

I am guessing it is a bug. Maybe google needs to fix this, or at least give clear documentation about this fact?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to resolve. Well mostly trial and error sort of thing.

1. In Android Studio, Go to file => settings => System Settings => Android SDk to confirm you have the SDK installed for the android version you're running. To confirm the android version you have click on AVD manager, it should be shown on Target.
2. Check that you have internet connection in your emulator, a cold reboot should help fix that, if not Wipe Data.
3. Check that you can open Google map on your android emulator.
4. Go to emulator settings which that 3 horizontal dots or ellipses and go to settings, OpenGL ES API Level to Auto Select.
5. Also make sure minSdkVersion 20 in android/app/build.gradle

Hope this helps anyone struggling at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
later I realised that i havent given my API Key in AndroidManifest.xml
I resolve it by root Directory => android => app => src => main =>AndroidManifest.xml
there you can find your meta data inside Application tag of google, it will be just like

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this problem ,
1 - at first you need to add these permissions under the manifest tag in the manifest file :

[image]

2 - you need to add this meta data tag under the application tag in the manifest file :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
       android:value="your api key"/>
```

3 - this feature from google runs only with min sdk equals to 21 , so you need to upgrade your min sdk to 21 at least by replace the defaultConfig in the gradle file (Module:android.app) by the next lines :

```
    defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.clean_architecture"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

[image]

but you will need to change the package name to your package name.

4 - go to the google api and set up your package name and the sha of your app so you can access the api through this application.